# python - Count number of occurrences of each number

Tags: python, json

I have a long string of numbers separated by commas. I can search and count the number of occurrences of most numbers, or more accurately, 2 digit numbers.

IF I have a number sequences like:
`1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,1,8,9,10,11,12,1,1,2`
and I want to count how many times the number `1` appears I should really get `5`.

However, because it is counting the `1` in `10`,`11` and `12`, I am getting `9`.

Does anyone know how to make the below code match ONLY whole "strings"?

```
def mostfreq(numString):
    import json 
    maxNum=45
    count=1
    list={}
    while count <= maxNum:
        list[count] = 0
        count+=1
    #numString is the array with all the numbers in it
    count=1
    topTen = ""
    while count <= maxNum:
        list[count]=numString.count(str(count))
        topTen = topTen+json.dumps(
        {count: list[count]},
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=4)+","
        count+=1
    response_generator = ( "["+topTen[:-1]+"]" )
    return HttpResponse(response_generator)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On 2.7+, just `split` and use the `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
numstring = "1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,1,8,9,10,11,12,1,1,2"
numcount = Counter(numstring.split(','))
```

or, Pre-2.7:

```
from collections import defaultdict
numstring = "1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,1,8,9,10,11,12,1,1,2"
numcount = defaultdict(int)
for num in numstring.split(','):
    numcount[num] += 1
```

If you want to use `count`:

```
numstring = "1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,1,8,9,10,11,12,1,1,2"
numlist = numstring.split(',')
numcount = dict((num, numlist.count(num)) for num in set(numlist))
```

but it's O(m*n) rather than O(n) because it iterates the list of numbers once for each unique number.

Comment: Which version of Python is this for? I tried it on 2.6.7 and I don't have Counter inside collections.

Comment: @Josh `Counter` is 2.7+, as I said (maybe I added it after you saw it), but the `defaultdict` replacement is 2.5+.

Comment: Plus one for backwards compatibiliy (a lot of people use Django etc with 2.6).

Comment: Very true. I'm actually using Django/python 2.6 myself! @agf, I've gotten part of the code working. The problem is, I'm tryin to sort by the frequency. I've tried using the above code with `sortedString=sorted(numcount, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` but I get an error saying `global name 'operator' is not defined` even though I've imported `from operator import itemgetter`. Any help?? Thanks.`

Comment: Also, as I'm outputting in `JSON`, I've tried sort it in the `json.dumps` code, but the `sort_keys=true` just sorts by the number on the left, not the frequency: `outputString+=json.dumps({num: numcount[num]},sort_keys=True,indent=4)+","`

Comment: @eoinzy You need to do `numcount.iteritems()` not just `numcount` or you'll just get the keys not the keys and values. If you do `from operator import itemgetter` then you just use `key=itemgetter(1)`. If you do `import operator`, then you do `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`.