# How many times words (from list) do occur in string [python]

Tags: python

I have a string for instance

```
message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

and a large list of words. I would like to get the count (int) of how many times those words occur in string.
If list is

```
words = ["the","over","azy","dog"]
```

It would return 4 (not 5). It shouldn't count word "the" 2 times. Each word only once!

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - Count number of occurences of each number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439578/python-count-number-of-occurences-of-each-number)

Comment: Means you want to check whether they are present or noy not the count right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of occurrences of a given substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899905/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-given-substring-in-a-string)

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have tried?

Comment: `'azy'` doesn't occur.

Comment: yes it does  @PeterWood

Comment: @user2468160 You need to define what a word is then.

Comment: @user2468160 Is `'he la`' a word?

Comment: if message is "abcdfefgeodlllssswaaäälöpå" then "waa" is inside it. Is "waa" a word? I don't know

Comment: @user2468160 They are your requirements. You decide. I guess you mean character sequence rather than word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for substrings also i.e `azy` in `lazy`, you need to check each word from words is `in`  each substring of message:

```
message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

words = ["the","over","azy","dog"]
print(sum(s in word for word in set(message.lower().split()) for s in words))
4
```

Or simply check if each word from words is contained in the string:

```
print(sum(word in message for word in words))
4
```

You also need to call lower on the string if you want to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

```
len(set(message.split()) & set(words))
```